# MongoDB: Update outer array and nested arrays in single update

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, mongodb-update

Document structure in `cities` collection is like this

**cities**

```
  {
   _id:  ObjectId("5e78ec62bb5b406776e92fac"),
   city_name: "Mumbai",
   ...
   ...
   subscriptions: [
    {
       _id: 1,
       category: "Print Magazine",
       subscribers: 183476
       options: [
         {
            name: "Time",
            subscribers: 56445
         },
         {
            name: "The Gentlewoman",
            subscribers: 9454
         },
         {
            name: "Gourmand",
            subscribers: 15564
         }
         ...
         ...
       ]
     },
     {
       _id: 2,
       category: "RSS Feed",
       subscribers: 2645873
       options: [
         {
            name: "Finance",
            subscribers: 168465
         },
         {
            name: "Politics",
            subscribers: 56945
         },
         {
            name: "Entrepreneurship",
            subscribers: 56945
         },
         ...
         ...
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

Now when a user subscribes like below

```
{
  cityId: 5e78ec62bb5b406776e92fac
  selections: [
    {
      categoryId: 1,
      options : ["Time", "Gourmand"]
    }, 
    {
      categoryId: 2, 
      selected: ["Politics", "Entrepreneurship"]
    }    
  ]
}
```

I want to update the following in the `cities` document

- Increment subscribers for "Print Magazine" by 1

  - Increment subscribers for "Time" by 1
  - Increment subscribers for "Gourmand" by 1
- Increment subscribers for "RSS Feed" by 1

  - Increment subscribers for "Politics" by 1
  - Increment subscribers for "Entrepreneurship" by 1

So when an item is subscribed, its subscribers count is incremented by 1. And the category it falls into, its subscriber count is also incremented by 1.

I want to achieve this in a single update query. Any tips how can I do this?

**Use case details**

Each user's subscription details are stored in `user_subscription_details` collection(not listed here). `subscriptions` property in `cities` holds just the subscription summary for each city.

Comment: _user subscribes_ data is a JSON (not a collection document)? An update with aggregation might be possible.

Comment: @prasad_does it matter ? since I need to update parts of the document and not the whole document.

Comment: You want update `city_subscriptions` based on `user subscribes`?

Comment: @Valijon yes. each document represents a city and its subscriptions.

Comment: Is `user suscribers` stored in separate collection? We need to perform aggregation with `$out` as last stage to override whole collection (said by prasad_)

Comment: @Valijon, yes it is stored in user_subscription_details collection. And city_subscriptions holds more like a subscription summary for each city.

Comment: One more question: What is the criteria to pick documents from `user_subscription_details`? I mean, this collection removes / marks by any flag **already taken documents**  to avoid increment twicely?

Comment: @Valijon this is a one time operation that takes place when user registers. So duplicate increments should not be a problem.

Comment: This should be possible with arrayFilters.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to it with the following query

```
db.cities.updateOne(
{
   _id : ObjectId("5e78ec62bb5b406776e92fac")
},
{ 
   $inc: { 
     "subscriptions.$[category].subscribers" : 1,
     "subscriptions.$[category].options.$[option].subscribers" : 1
   }
},
{ multi: true,
   arrayFilters: [
     { "category._id": {$in: ["1", "2"]} },
     { "option.name": {$in: ["Time", "Gourmand", "Politics", "Entrepreneurship"]} } 
   ]
}
)
```

**Brief Explanation**

- First the document is matched with `_id`.
- In update block we will declare the fields to be updated

  - "subscriptions.$[`?`].subscribers" : 1,
  - "subscriptions.$[`?`].options.$[`?`].subscribers" : 1

> I have used `?` here to show we don't know yet for which elements  in the array we need to do these update. Which we can declare in the next block by filtering the array elements that need to be updated.

- In filter block we filter array elements on some condition

  - { "category._id": {$in: ["1", "2"]} }
  - { "option.name": {$in: ["Time", "Gourmand", "Politics", "Entrepreneurship"]} }

> First we filter the elements in the outer array by `_id` i.e only subscription categories whose `_id` is either `1` or `2`.
>   Next, we filter the elements in the inner `options` array on the `name` field. Elements which will pass both filters will get updated.

Note: `category` in `category._id` and `option` in `option.name` can be any name. But the same name is to be used for fields path in update block.

For, Spring Boot MongoOperation translation of this query look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60926880/4057038)