# Building ArrayFilters update in Spring Data MongoDB with MongoOperation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, nosql, spring-mongodb

I am using Spring boot `2.2.1.RELEASE`. How can I write the below MongoDB update query with Spring MongoOperation

```
db.cities.updateOne(
  {
    _id : ObjectId("5e78ec62bb5b406776e92fac")
  },
  { 
    $inc: { 
      "subscriptions.$[category].subscribers" : 1,
      "subscriptions.$[category].options.$[option].subscribers" : 1
    }
  },
  { multi: true,
    arrayFilters: [
      { "category._id": {$in: ["1", "2"]} },
      { "option.name": {$in: ["Time", "Gourmand", "Politics", "Entrepreneurship"]} } 
    ]
  }
)
```

I have tried the following

```
Update update = new Update().inc("subscriptions.$[category].subscribers", 1).inc("subscriptions.$[category].options.$[option].subscribers", 1).filterArray(Criteria.where("category._id").in(Arrays.asList("1", "2")).andOperator(Criteria.where("option.name").in(Arrays.asList("Time", "Gourmand", "Politics", "Entrepreneurship"))));
UpdateResult result = mongoOperations.updateFirst(new Query(where("id").is(cityId)), update, CitiesDoc.class);
```

But I keep getting the following error

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Command failed with error 9 (FailedToParse): 'Unrecognized field in update operation: arrayFilters' on server localhost:56740. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Unrecognized field in update operation: arrayFilters", "code": 9, "codeName": "FailedToParse"}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9 (FailedToParse): 'Unrecognized field in update operation: arrayFilters' on server localhost:56740. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Unrecognized field in update operation: arrayFilters", "code": 9, "codeName": "FailedToParse"}

Not sure for which field it is giving the error. Some suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It worked with the following query

```
update = update.inc("subscriptions.$[category].subscribers", 1);
update = update.inc("subscriptions.$[category].options.$[option].subscribers", 1);
update = update.filterArray(Criteria.where("category._id").in(Arrays.asList("1", "2")));
update = update.filterArray(Criteria.where("option.name").in(Arrays.asList("Time", "Gourmand", "Politics", "Entrepreneurship")));

UpdateResult result = mongoOperations.updateFirst(new Query(where("id").is(cityId)), update, CitiesDoc.class);
```

But the cause for the error was MongoDB version. I am using [flabdoodle](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) as embedded MongoDB for testing. And the default MongoDB version is 3.5.5. Which I believe don not support `arrayFilters`. Updating the version to 4.x resolved the issue. You can look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58462875/4057038) on how to update the version to latest supported production version.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  mongodb:
    embedded:
      version: 4.0.2
```